# sending row id when RecyclerView item clicked

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview

I have prepared a Database in my asset folder . I have one `recyclerView` for showing the title in the database . Now  i want show `DetailActivity` with specific`id` . my means is show description of post . I think it can be done with intent , but i don't know how .

```
    public class FehrestRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FehrestRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context ctx;
    private List<Post> posts;

    //constructor
    public FehrestRecyclerAdapter(Context ctx, List<Post> posts) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.posts= posts;
    }

    //ViewHodler Pattern
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        private TextView txtTitle;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            txtTitle= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(v.getContext() , txtTitle.getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext() , DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("postId" , "id");
            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    //OncreateViewHolder
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_row , parent , false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    //OnBindViewHolder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Post current = Post.get(position);

        holder.txtTitle.setText(current.getTitle());
    }

    //getItemCount method
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }
}
```

i have a 3 columns in my database

> 1.id 2.title 3.desc

and 3 methods in my Post model Class :

> 1. getId() 2.getTitle() 3.getDesc()

as you can see i can send intent to `DetailActivity` . But i don't know how can i achieve to sending specific id to `DetailActivity`. thanks

Comment: simple, use this adapter: https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b, note `getItemId` method

Comment: @kiana rahimi: have u tried my solution. just want to know it's working or not.Thanks

Comment: yes , thankyou . but i think for @Surabhi Singh is easier for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make one Variable id in ViewHolder and assign that in onBindViewHolder() , I updated the code according to that.

```
public class FehrestRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FehrestRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context ctx;
private List<Post> posts;

//constructor
public FehrestRecyclerAdapter(Context ctx, List<Post> posts) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.posts= posts;
}

//ViewHodler Pattern
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextView txtTitle;
    private int id;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        txtTitle= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Toast.makeText(v.getContext() , txtTitle.getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext() , DetailActivity.class);
        // here pass id through intent
        intent.putExtra("postId" , id);
        itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}

//OncreateViewHolder
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_row , parent , false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

//OnBindViewHolder
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Post current = Post.get(position);

    holder.txtTitle.setText(current.getTitle());

    // add this line
    holder.id = Post.get(postion).getId();

}

//getItemCount method
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return posts.size();
}
}
```

Comment: wouldn't holder.id in onBindViewHolder() be: "current.getId()", since you define current?

Comment: yes both are same since current = Post.get(position);

Answer (score 2):

> How can i achieve to sending specific id to DetailActivity

Use `setTag` method of `holder.txtTitle` TextView for storing id with TextView and call getTag inside onClick of `View` Click like:

**1.** In `onBindViewHolder` save `current` using setTag:

```
  holder.txtTitle.setTag(current);
  holder.txtTitle.setText(current.getTitle());
```

**2.** In onClick of View use  `getTag` as:

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     txtTitle= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
     Post current=(Post)txtTitle.getTag();
     intent.putExtra("postId" , current.getId());
     intent.putExtra("postTitle" , current.getTitle());
     ....
   }
```

Comment: tag is not used so why do you use `setTag`? id should be set in ViewHolder as selvin said

Comment: @pskink: hi, means? not getting you please explain

Comment: what do you need `Post current=(Post)txtTitle.getTag();` for if you are not using it? as i sad (and selvin) id should be set in ViewHolder

Comment: @pskink: Thanks, both `getId ` and `getTitle ` is getter method inside `current ` object.

Comment: see the answer of Surabhi Singh, it should be done like this, not by using weird setTag / getTag

Comment: @pskink: Lots of way to do one thing no issue. She is doing in different way using variable  and my answer different.

Comment: @pskink: you mean my answer is wrong ? let me know why? and also if OP want to access description and title also with id in onCreate method then ?

Comment: i didn't say your solution is wrong: i said her solution is a correct one, her solution is like 2 * 5 = 10, while yours is like 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 10, both results are the right ones, but everybody agrees 2 * 5 is a correct one